# parsing kubectl json output with jq or jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, jq, jsonpath

I would like to select, and list the crds which are containing the "v1beta1" in the

> .spec.versions.*.name

The versions part of the crd object looks similar like this

```
    "versions": [
      {
        "name": "v1alpha2",
        "served": true,
        "storage": true,
        "subresources": {
          "status": {}
        },
        "name": "v1beta1"
        "served": true,
        "storage": true,
        "subresources": {
          "status": {}
        }
      }
    ]
```

I tried some different queries like the following, but no success.

```
$ kubectl get crd -ojson | jq -r '.items[] | map(select(.spec.versions[] | contains("v1beta1"))).metadata.name'
jq: error (at <stdin>:250345): Cannot index string with string "spec"
```

Jsonpath solution would be also great. I tried something like this without success.

```
$ kubectl get crd -ojsonpath="{range .items.*.spec.versions.*}{.name[?(@=='v1beta1')].metadata.name}{'\n'}{end}"
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Could you please add the original json to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show the name using jsonpath: `kubectl get crd -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.spec.versions[].name=="v1beta1")].metadata}{.name}{"\n"}'`

Comment: That's doing exactly what I would like to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could base a jq solution on:

`.spec.versions[] | select(.name | contains("v1beta1"))`

or similar, e.g.

`.spec.versions[] | select(.name | startswith("v1beta1"))`

Comment: That’s not working for me in this form. My problem is that in the json object I try to parse, contains a root object .items[] which is a list of objects already.
In this form my query would look like similar, but it’s not working for me.
```
$ kubectl get crd -ojson | jq -r '.items[].spec.version[] | select(.name | contains("v1beta1"))'
jq: error (at <stdin>:250345): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Comment: As @0stone0 said, it would be helpful for everyone concerned if a complete example were provided.  See also the [mcve] guidelines.